# How to capture a HDMI device on Ubuntu/Kubuntu?

Tags: hdmi, camera, capture

I have a Fujifilm S2800HD, that can record HD films, the camera has mini-HDMI output to conect to TV, but i want to know if that is possible to capture what the camera is showing on its own LCD. I know that VLC player has a feature to capture external devices, but seems that HDMI is not present. Is there a way to capture what the camera is recording real-time? I buy this camera not just to take photos, but to record screencasts for a e-Learning business.

Comment: It's a shame that this question got closed. The detailed description is very specialized I agree, but the headline is not. HDMI is the most widespread video interface nowadays so capturing from it a quite obvious thing to do.